# How to represent a point of intersection in the given graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to represent a point of intersection of line CD and AB by Q,  and then want to shade a particular region PBQF, but facing error in the following code , please help...

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,5)--(0,0)--(4,0)node(f){F} %(2,0)node(a){A}--(0,4)node(b){B}
     %(3,0)node(c){C}--(0,2.4)node(d){D} 
     (4,0)--(0,2)node(e){E} (0,5)node(p){P};

        \draw[name path=P3]  (2,0)node(a){A}--(0,4)node(b){B};

        \draw[name path=P4]  (3,0)node(c){C}--(0,2.4)node(d){D};


        \path [name intersections={of=P3 and P4,by=Q}]; 

    \node [dot=Q]  at (Q) {};


        \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}    % select background
    \path [fill=orange!50] (p.center)--(b.center) --  (p.center) -- (f.center) --(Q.center)-- cycle;

    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Could you turn your code into a complete example, so that it can be compiled without any modifications?

Comment: Your code contains errors.

Comment: One thing you can think about first is the order of the coordinates you use when you draw the filled polygon. You go from p to b then *back to p* then f then Q then back to start (p).

Answer (score 2):

Your code fragment is not useful. It contain errors and some clutter, so it is almost impossible to figured out what you like to draw. Based on my guessing and my previous answers on your question, see, if the following MWE gives what you after:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                intersections,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,
        dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1pt},
 every edge/.style = {draw, shorten >=-12mm},
every label/.style = {inner sep=1.5pt}
                        ]
\coordinate (o);
\coordinate[label=below:A,right=2 of o] (a);
\coordinate[label=below:C,right=1 of a] (c);
\coordinate[label=below:F,right=1 of c] (f);
%
\coordinate[label=left: E,above=2 of o] (e);
\coordinate[label=left: D,above=1 of e] (d);
\coordinate[label=left: B,above=2 of d] (b);
\coordinate[label=left: P,above=2 of b] (p);
%

\draw  (p) |- (f);
\draw[name path=AB]  (a) -- (b);
\draw[name path=CD]  (c) -- (d);
\path [name intersections={of=AB and CD,by=q}] node[dot, label=above right:Q]  at (q) {};
%
\scoped[on background layer]
\fill[orange!50] (b) -- (d) -- (q) -- (a) -- (c) -- (q); % it is not clear, what you like to fill ... so two options
\fill[green!20,semitransparent] (p) -- (b) -- (q) -- (c) -- (f) -- (q);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]